# How to determine the formula for calculating the enthalpy change of a reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

$$\ce{4 HCl(g) + O2(g) -> 2 Cl2(g) + 2H2O(g)}$$

In the reaction above, knowing the enthalpy of formation of each individual compound, in order to calculate the standard enthalpy change of the reaction, how do I determine whether it is:
$\pu{[products] - [reactants]}$ or $\pu{[reactants] - [products]}$
.

Answer (score 1):

There's a general principle that applies anytime you calculate a change in a property:
The change in the value of a property in going from an initial state to a final state is always:

```
             value(final state) - value(initial state)
```

For instance, what is the change in elevation (which we'll call height, h; not to be confused with enthalpy, H!) when we go from 500 m to 1000 m?  Here h(initial state) = 500 m and  h(final state) = 1000 m, so:
$$\Delta h = h(\text{final state}) – h(\text{initial state}) = \text{1000 m – 500 m = 500 m}$$

Likewise, what is the change in temperature when going from 60 C to 40 C?  Here T(initial state) = 60 C and  T(final state) = 40 C, so:
$$\Delta T = T(\text{final state}) - T(\text{initial state}) = \text{40 C - 60 C = –20 C}$$

Calculating enthalpy change is no different:

$$\Delta H = H(\text{final state}) - H(\text{initial state})$$

If we want to calculate the enthalpy change for a chemical reaction, the initial state consists of reactants, and the final state consists of products.  Thus:

$$\Delta H_{rxn} = H(\text{final state}) - H(\text{initial state})=\Delta H_f(\text{products}) - \Delta H_f(\text{reactants})$$

**I.e., the fact that it's products minus reactants has nothing to do with the nature of enthalpy.**  Rather, "products minus reactants" *follows directly from the basic mathematical convention we use to calculate the change (in anything).*

Answer (score 0):

The enthalpy change is always Products minus Reactants.

Comment: I'm curious as to the rationale for giving this answer two downvotes.  I personally had given it an upvote.

Comment: @ChetMiller One downvote is mine. Even though the answer is, of course, correct, it is too brief and in my opinion should be a comment as it lacks explanation as to *why* it is so (or even citation of the origin). I intensely disagree with the opinion that answers using such dogmatic postulates being useful as it's not how scientific method operates and not how teaching should be done.

Comment: I agree with @andselisk. I would like to humbly request him to edit his answer accordingly, and share his valuable knowledge with us all. Expecting an informative answer soon :) Or else we could have had a stimulating discussion in the comment section as well.